# Resolution Change Positioning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to position NSRects by using `NSRect mainFrame = [[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame];` and setting that as my x origin for the rects like so:

`outlineBox.origin.x = (mainFrame.size.width - width2) / 2.0 * (some positioning number);`

width2 is just a float value.

However when I change resolution that last multiplied positioning number is way off to the new resolution frame, what can I do to solve this? Thanks!